# wordpress how to add javascript to footer and maybe load them after page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

am trying to move javascript in wordpress to footer and i am able to using the code below , sticking this to my themes functions.php , how ever some of my slider.js or other .js gets affected and my sliders in homepage stops showing up and shows white blank area.

i think these are the javascript is being affects not loading the slider in homepage

```
http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/LayerSlider/static/js/layerslider.transitions.js
http://exmple.com/wp-content/plugins/LayerSlider/static/js/layerslider.kreaturamedia.jquery.js
```

now what can i do to fix it.

```
function remove_head_scripts() {
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_scripts');
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 9);
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 1);

add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_print_scripts', 5);
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 5);
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 5);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_head_scripts' );
```

is there a way maybe i can load these javascript after the page is loaded up or maybe exclude them , what can i do to improve the speed and make this work the same time.

Comment: Plugins and themes expect functions to be available at certain times. Sometimes it isn't possible to move all the JS to the footer with certain themes and functions.

Answer (score 0):

Each theme is a little different, but you would have to see how the JS files are enqueued. To get a JS file into the footer (example):

```
function themeslug_enqueue_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-js', 'filename.js', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themeslug_enqueue_script' );
```

The important part of the wp_enqueue_script function is the last. 'true' will set the JS file to load in the footer, 'false' will load js files to the head area of the page.

For reference: [WordPress Codex wp_enqueue_scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts)

WordPress won't know what to do with the function you've created.